# QTextEdit. In textChanged slot change colors for some words and restore

Tags: qt, qtextedit

I need to paint some words in QTextEdit by other colors.

```
void Wnd::onTextChanged()
{
    QString s = ui->textEdit->toPlainText();
    s = addColors(s);

    ui->textEdit->blockSignals(true);
    ui->textEdit->setHtml(s);
    ui->textEdit->blockSignals(false);
}
```

`QTextEditor::setHtml` set cursor and visible region in the beginning. But I need to my `QTextEdit` using will be no different from simple `QTextEdit` using.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are doing that wrong, creating big overhead. You should do this like that:

```
void Wnd::onTextChanged()
{
    QTextDocument *doc = ui->textEdit->document();

    // clears old formating
    QTextCursor cursor(doc);
    cursor.select(QTextCursor::Document);
    cursor.setCharFormat(QTextCharFormat());

    Q_FOREACH(QString word, wordsToColor) {
        QTextCursor cursor = doc->find(word);

        while(cursor.hasSelection()) {
             cursor.setCharFormat(someTextCharFormat);
             cursor = doc->find(word, cursor); // next word
        }
    }
}
```

It is also possible that you are trying to do something what is already solved: http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/richtext-syntaxhighlighter.html

Comment: To iterate `wordsToColor` in C++11 you can use the [range for](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/range-for): `for (auto word : wordsToColor) { ... }`. `Q_FOREACH` or simply `foreach` is needed with pre-C++11 compilers.